# Phonegap deviceready not firing using Cordova 2.2.0 in iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, cordova

I am building a PhoneGap App. Unfortunately, when deploying to iOS devices and simulators the `deviceready` event never fires. I'm using Phonegap 2.2.0.

When I deploy the same code to Android (using the Android-specific `cordova.js` file of course) the App will work perfectly.

When I replace the `deviceready` with a jQuery-`ready()` the app will load on iOS as well, yet it will then lack access to the device specific APIs.

The `cordova.js` is loaded as I will see a simple alert message that I put inside of it, yet `deviceready` never fires and the APIs are never exposed.

My HTMLs `head`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script> <!-- yes it is the iOS version -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

My JS:

```
function doStuff(){
//app functionality
}
document.addEventListener('deviceready', doStuff, false);
```

But somehow stuff will only get done on Android...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in my html I have a  onload that triggers that adding of an event listener to deviceready

```
      function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("we are an app");
        MyApp.initialize_phonegap();
      }

      function onBodyLoad() {   
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      }

    </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
```

Comment: That seems to be the cause of the issue, thanks. But to be honest I am still a little to puzzled as I don't quite understand why I do need to nest an event handler inside another event handler. The `addEventListener` method should be available from the start as well as `document`, shouldn't it? Do you have an explanation for that behavior?

Comment: did you have a body onload=  ?  That tripped me up the first time. I agree with you it'd be strange if the double event handler setup was the solution.

Comment: No, I didn't have one in the first place as I didn't get the "logic", when using it "somehow" works, yet I went ahead to using the approach that the default project setup uses, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

To add to olore's answer I ended up using the approach that the code in the default project (that gets built from the `./create` script) uses (which is different to the code in the **[Event docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#Events)**).

The major differences are (I do not really know which one of these actually are to be taken into account):

- `cordova-2.2.0.js` is located in the root folder
- `<script>`s are included right before the closing `</body>`-tag and not in the document's `head`
- `deviceready`-handling works like:

  ```
  var app = {
  // Application Constructor
  initialize: function() {
      this.bindEvents();
  },
  // Bind Event Listeners
  //
  // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
  // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
  bindEvents: function() {
      document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
  },
  // deviceready Event Handler
  //
  // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
  // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
  onDeviceReady: function() {
      app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
      myApp.start(); //this is where I put the call to my App's functionality relying on device APIs
  },
  // Update DOM on a Received Event
  receivedEvent: function(id) { // I didn't really use this, yet I left it in here as it's in the demo
      var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
      var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
      var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

      listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
      receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

      console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
  }
  };
  ```
- The last `<script>` tag just calls `app.initialize()`

This seems to work quite fine on iOS and Android and is a little more understandable to me than the double handler nesting from the docs.

Comment: i think it goes like this for external files,simulator or all:
-phonegap starts
-loads whole app
-fires device ready event
-start running js
-assign event
-but it's already fired.

basically loaded first then ran later which messes up the logic.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to make a difference if you are adding the **deviceready** listener **before** or **after** the **cordova.js**:

I was not able to find any documentation on this, but cordova.js intercepts calls to addEventListener + removeEventListener and calls only deviceready callbacks which has been added **before** cordova.js.

Solution in my case was just to rearrange the script order:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('deviceready', ...)
</script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if you accidentally include the cordova.js script twice, then the deviceready event does not fire.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I got it to work by adding the device plugin.

```
$ cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```

To verify:

```
$ cordova plugin ls
```