# PhoneGAP, JQuery Mobile Application won't Work on ipad 3 ios 6

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, ios6

i am building a phoneGap, jQuery Mobile Application for ios and android i am using cordova 2.3
with XCode 4.5.2 and SDK 6, the problem is when trying to work the application on ipad3 (with ios 6.0.1) it will not function well, even though its working rather fine on ipad 2 (with ios 5.1.1)

my HTML Page :

```
<script src="js/cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/myjs.js"></script>
<script>
 function init(){
  document.addEventListener("deviceready",getUserProfiles,false);
  }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
```

the "getUserProfiles" function is a function in "myjs.js" which have a callback function as so:

```
function getUserProfiles(){
  readFile("directory","filename",callBackFunc);
}
function callbackfunc (){
 //do stuff
}
```

this is not working on the ipad 3 , but working on ipad 2, another thing when working the Application on ipad3 if i closed the app then re entered it the functions will fire one by one each time i close it and reopen it.

i would like where i went wrong on my code ;

i have researched for anything close to my problem to build on it , the only thing i got is that the "addEventListener" is not firing well on ios 6 i have changed it many times but still with the same results.

what happen is the page appear ok but the java Script and JQuery functions are not triggered when running on the ipad3 so the pages appear to be empty because everything is created dynamically when page  on load or device ready.

thanx in advance.

****UPDATE : readFile Function ****

```
function readFile(directoryName,fileName,callBackFunc) {
alert("read = "+directoryName+"file = "+ fileName);
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
                         var tmpPath = directoryName;
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory(tmpPath, {create: false, exclusive: false}, function (dirEntry) {
                                 var directoryReader = dirEntry;
        directoryReader.getFile(fileName, {create: false, exclusive: false}, function (fileEntry){
                                gotFileEntry(fileEntry,callBackFunc);
        }, fail);
    }, fail);
}, fail);
}


function gotFileEntry(fileEntry,callBackFunc) {
fileEntry.file(function (file){
               gotFile(file, callBackFunc);
}, fail);
 }

function gotFile(file,callBackFunc){
readAsText(file,callBackFunc);
}
function readAsText(file, callBackFunc) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    console.log("Read as text");
    console.log(evt.target.result);
    jsonobject3 = evt.target.result;
    callBackFunc(evt.target.result);
};
reader.readAsText(file);
}

var fail = function(evt) {
 console.log("error in read from nested directory");
};
```

Comment: try removing "onload=.." might be something to do with a double event handler
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196130/phonegap-deviceready-not-firing-using-cordova-2-2-0-in-ios

Comment: i tried that and it wont work, and i tried to use the "eventListener" without the calling function also it didn't work, @ClintonWard so if you have any other ideas i'll be gladly considering them.

Comment: Maybe for jquery-mobile you should use $(document).on('pageinit', function() {});

Comment: the jQuery(document).on('pageinit',function(){}); will result in an error that wont even allow the page to load the basic html elements; it will show an empty white page. so any other ideas.

Comment: are you referencing the 2 jquery files? because it's not in the code above

Comment: yes i am, and i was doing a research about the matter i found that the 'eventListener' function is being called but the problem that it does not call the function inside it, even though the same function was called before, and i am trying to check for changes in the plist or config.xml, so if u have any idea plz share it with me

Comment: can you add the readfile method

Comment: i just updated and added the readFile Function

Answer (score 0):

**Am sorry that i had to post an answer on my own question ;**

what i have found that on IOS 6

```
 document.addEventListener('deviceready',deviceReady, false)
```

will be fired once when the app is open , "this was the reason why my app was malfunctioning" .

so what i have done is adding the

```
addEventListener
```

function on the first Page, and using the

```
jQuery.changePage('page.html')
```

method for navigation through the pages and inserting any JS code i want to be triggered when the page opens inside the

```
  data-role="page"
```

element in my html page and it will behave as the

```
addEventListener
```

function as so :

```
<div data-role="page">
    <script>
        //my script
    </script>
    <!-- the rest of my HTML element here -->
</div>
```

i don't know if this is the best way to do so , but it worked fine for me.

so if anybody have a better idea please do tell.