# How to use Ripple Emulator for Windows to test PhoneGap application?

Tags: cordova, ripple

**Can Ripple emulator be used to test PhoneGap application under Windows?**

Either I'm doing something really bad or Ripple is not working at all in such environment.

I have installed Ripple Emulator extension for Chrome from Chrome Store. I navigated Chrome to my mobile app (served locally via XAMPP). I clicked Ripple icon next to Chrome omnibar and clicked `Enable` in opened window. I've selected proper platform (`Cordova 2.0`).

My application was reloaded in mobile-like look, simulating mobile device. Ripple was unable to read my configuration from `config.xml` file, but that is a well known bug (reported [here](https://github.com/blackberry/Ripple-UI/issues/743) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832776/phonegap-ripple-emulator-always-reports-malformed-config-xml)). I hope, this is not an issue that prevents me from using Ripple at all?

I've selected my device (`Samsung Nexus`) and begin to test my mobile device. Even first call to PhoneGap API has failed. I tried compass, but all I got was `Cannot call method 'watchHeading' of undefined`.

How can basic PhoneGap object be undefined? What am I missing? Can I test PhoneGap application under Windows in Chrome with Ripple Emulator or amy I missing the entire idea for what Ripple is?

I tried to help myself with Ripple documentation, but chapter "[Enable the Ripple emulator](http://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/getting_started_with_ripple_1866966_11.html)" is a complete garbage. I don't have even a sign of `Start Ripple Services` option in Ripple icon (only `Enable` and `Disable`) and when I click `Enable` there is no sign of the license agreement, that I could review and accept. I'm getting the feeling that this doc talks about something completely different than I use.

**How to use Ripple in Chrome to test PhoneGap application? What am I missing?**

Answer (score 29, accepted):

***tl;dr:** On contrary to what is said in PGB's docs, you **must** keep a copy of `cordova.js` file in your app's root directory and this file must be taken from exactly version 2.0 of PhoneGap, as latest version of Ripple Emulator  does not work neither with other version nor without this file.*

### Solution

I'm developing my PhoneGap apps using PhoneGap Build, not local PhoneGap environment. So -- as I was instructed -- I have deleted `phonegap.js` file from my application's webroot and only left reference to it in `index.html`. This is fine for PhoneGap Build, but absolutely **not** fine for Ripple Emulator.

Ever since I put that file back (actually `cordova.js` from `lib\android\example\assets\www\` folder from `phonegap-2.0.0.zip` I managed to see license, start Ripple Services and test working PhoneGap application locally.

Notice for people struggling with similar problem: Current version of Ripple Emulator uses `Cordova 2.0`. Make sure, that you download **right version** of PhoneGap and take `cordova.js` from it! Do not attempt to use `cordova.js` from newer version (currently `3.0.0`) as you may run into undetectable situations, including seeing many strange `alert()`'s and even hanging up overloaded Chrome.

*Always make sure, that you're using PhoneGap's JS file version, that maches the one behind Ripple.*

### Step by step

Key steps to be able to test PhoneGap application under Windows, using Chrome and Ripple Emulator:

1. Put `cordova.js` file back to your folder root and check the reference to it. You can grab it from `lib\android\example\assets\www\` folder from any downloadable version of PhoneGap (you should use `phonegap-2.0.0.zip` though, see above).
2. Install `Ripple Emulator` extension for your Chrome browser, using Chrome Store. Enable it.
3. Start your local webserver and run your HTML code of your mobile application through it (testing through direct file access is mainly possible in Ripple Emulator, but highly not advisable and may produce unpredictable results).
4. Click Ripple Emulator icon, right to your Chrome omnibar and then click `Enable` (or select proper option from context menu, right-clicking page).
5. Accept license agreement and select proper platform (`Cordova 2.0.0`).
6. Click Ripple Emulator icon again and click `Start Ripple Services` if they're not started automatically.
7. Set destination platform (device) and enjoy working PhoneGap application locally.

### Version and API differences

You also have to keep your eye for [PhoneGap API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/) and carefully check, what was available and how it was accessible in PhoneGap 2.0.0? For example, simple connection type checking has changed ever since that. In [2.9.0 API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#connection.type) it is done via `navigator.connection`, while in [2.0.0 API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#connection.type) it was accessed under the `navigator.network` interface.

Since Ripple Emulator uses PhoneGap 2.0.0, currently supported way of calling this object:

```
var networkState = navigator.connection.type;
```

will fail. You'll have to use it this way:

```
var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
```

Though you can select PhoneGap version, when compiling in PhoneGap Build (and you can force it to use version 2.0.0, though compile this code in an unchanged way), you will most likey want to develop your application using newest version of PhoneGap.

In this case, you have to use a "secured" approach, that will work in both Ripple and PhoneGap:

```
var networkState = ((navigator.connection) ? navigator.connection.type : ((navigator.network && navigator.network.connection) ? navigator.network.connection.type : 'unknown'));
```

Or you can declare some special variable:

```
var debugMode = typeof(window.tinyHippos) !== 'undefined';
```

And use it as a switch:

```
var networkState = (debugMode) ? navigator.network.connection.type : navigator.connection.type;
```

Hopefully, Ripple will be updated soon to newest PhoneGap so we could drop such *things* away.

Comment: That is fantastic info, thank you! I was wondering why I was getting all kinds of errors. Only 1.0 seemed to "work" and 2.0 failed all the time and it was because of the phonegap.js version differences.

Comment: i had this problem: solution included doing all above + downloading cordovra.js from somewhere + doing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196130/phonegap-deviceready-not-firing-using-cordova-2-2-0-in-ios    and then finally fixing choosing a version that i actually use in ripple emulator 1.00 if you use 2.00 and have 1.00 in config bad things will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Ripple should work with the latest versions of Phonegap, although you may get a few spurious error messages that popup during the page loading which are due to Ripple not quite being up-to-date with the latest Phonegap versions. Make sure you've included the Phonegap JS into your page. Try the following example - it works fine for me in Ripple:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.8.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function deviceready() {
            console.log("Device ready");
            navigator.compass.watchHeading(function(heading){
                document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = heading.trueHeading;
            },function(error){
                var errorType;
                switch(error.code){
                    case CompassError.COMPASS_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                        errorType = "Compass not supported";
                        break;
                    case CompassError.COMPASS_INTERNAL_ERR:
                        errorType = "Compass internal error";
                        break;
                    default:
                        errorType = "Unknown compass error";
                }
                document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = errorType;
            });
        }
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceready, true);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
        <p>Heading: <span id="heading"></span></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've just found the very same thing -- missing `cordova.js` file (not required for PhoneGap Build). I also found, that using it from version `2.9.0` fails in Ripple with many strange errors, so I reverted it back to version `2.0.0`.