# Testing phonegap apps in the browser with Ripple

Tags: javascript, cordova

What's the proper way to test a PhoneGap app in the browser using Ripple? Is there any configuration I need to do?

I've got a "hello world" app made with PhoneGap and I'd like to test it in the browser instead of firing up a phone emulator for every change. I'm running it on a local webserver. I used [http://emulate.phonegap.com](http://emulate.phonegap.com/) to head to the address (eg, `localhost:8888/sites/hello/www`). The app starts to load, but I get a 404 for `phonegap.js`. The path it's checking is `localhost:8888/sites/hello/www/phonegap.js` -- should this be provided by the emulator? Do I need to dig up the file? I'm using the stock hello world app, so I expected the pieces to be in place.

Comment: Maybe this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695875/how-to-use-ripple-emulator-for-windows-to-test-phonegap-application

Comment: Also some detail about ripple : http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/2/6/Using-Ripple-for-PhoneGap-Development

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to provide phonegap.js for Ripple to work - just insert a script tag in the `<head>` of your index.html to point at it. Note Ripple will not work properly with Phonegap 3.x, so use the JS from a Phonegap 2.x release - I'm using cordova-2.9.0.js from the Android package. Ripple will only work in Google Chrome.

Incidentally, you can open the index.html file directly in Chrome from the filesystem, without needing a local webserver, if you use the `--allow-file-access-from-files` option when you start chrome - just add it to the shortcut, e.g. `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files`

Answer (score 11):

Here's how I setup a machine for development with Cordova. These steps show what needs to be downloaded as well as creating a simple hello world app with the last couple steps launching the ripple emulator to test the app.

Linux Mint 15: How to setup nodejs, npm, Apache Cordova, Ripple, Android SDK for Android Development

References:

Cordova Android Guide:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

NodeJS Guide:
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

NPM Cordova Guide:
https://npmjs.org/package/cordova

Prereqs - folder names and locations are all variables meaning they can be whatever you want

-Must use chrome for ripple emulator

1. Download android sdk - http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html
2. Unzip folder
3. Rename folder to adt-bundle
4. change directories to your home folder. example. cd /home/brian
5. create a folder named Development
6. Move adt-bundle to Development  example. /home/brian/Development/adt-bundle
7. export PATH=${PATH}:/home/brian/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools:/home/brian/Development/adt-bundle/sdk/tools
8. sudo apt-get install ant
9. type android  the android sdk window will pop up check api17 and install
10. sudo apt-get remove nodejs nodejs-dev npm
11. sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
12. sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
13. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
14. sudo apt-get update
15. sudo apt-get install nodejs
16. nodejs -v
17. npm -v
18. npm install -g cordova
19. npm install -g ripple-emulator
20. cd /home/brian/Development/
21. cordova create hello "HelloWorld"
22. cd hello
23. cordova platform add android
24. cordova build
25. cd /home/brian/Development/hello/platforms/android/assets/www
26. ripple emulate -port 1234
27. open chrome
28. navigate to localhost:1234/index.html?enableripple=cordova-2.0.0-Nexus4
29. Back at the terminal you can press Ctrl+c to kill the server

Comment: To run ripple, you should be in root folder of your project. In my root folder of project, I have hooks, merges, platforms, plugins, .cordova and www folders. And then run command 
`ripple emulate -port 12345`.
It will open your application in your browser (in my case it is chrome:suggestion, make chrome as default browser)

Answer (score 8):

**Important:** uninstall ripple Chrome-Addon first!!

### Solution 1: 'patch it!'

To test your phonegap3 applications in ripple you have to use the latest version (0.9.19) from the [apache git repository](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator-ripple.git) and patch it with the `ripple_phonegap3.patch` located at [this git-repo](http://github.com/fastrde/stuff). Follow the instructions in the README.md file located in the same repository.

The new version of ripple is not longer a chrome extension. It's now a nodejs/expressjs webserver to support other browsers as well.

### Solution 2: 'step-by-step' (only when you use phonegap3 exclusively)

- Download ripple

  ```
  git clone https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator-ripple.git
  ```
- Edit `lib/server/emulate/hosted.js`

Add lines

```
    var PG3_SCRIPTTAG_OLD= /<script type="text\/javascript" src="phonegap.js"><\/script>/;
    var PG3_SCRIPTTAG_NEW= '<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>';
    doc = doc.replace(PG3_SCRIPTTAG_OLD, PG3_SCRIPTTAG_NEW);
```

in `function localInjection()` between

```
        var doc = data.replace(HEAD_TAG,
                  '<head>' +
                    '<script>' +
                        BOOTSTRAP_FROM_IFRAME +
                    '</script>');
```

and

```
        res.send(doc);
```

- run `./configure`
- run `jake`
- use `bin/riddle`

lg

fastrde

Answer (score 1):

Icenium has a free trial and it's pretty awesome:  http://www.icenium.com/